# SQL Pivot for text columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a large set of IDs with titles, and I want to link multiple Names to the IDs to fill as separate columns. I understand I need to do a pivot but I cannot understand what I meant to do as I want text to be pivoted, not a value.

E.g.

TBL1:

```
ID   Title
1   TestA
2   TestB    
3   TestC etc.
```

and for each ID I have names
TBL2

```
Name ID
Jack 1
John 1
Ted  1
Bill 2
Nigel 3
Trevor 3
etc
```

etc

I want the data to appear as

```
ID Title Person_1 Person_2 Person_3 ... Person_n 
1 TestA  Jack     John     Ted
2 TestB  Bill
3 TestC  Nigel   Trevor
```

Please could someone help with the code for this pivot. There is no set amount of people for each group but varying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance the maximum number of `name`s per `id`, you can enumerate them with `row_number()`, then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
    max(case when t2.rn = 1 then t2.name end) person_1,
    max(case when t2.rn = 2 then t2.name end) person_2,
    max(case when t2.rn = 3 then t2.name end) person_3,
    ...
from t1
inner join (
    select t2.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by name) rn
    from t2
) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: thank you so much! The row_number() over(partition by id order by name) was a life saver! without knowing the name of this function its hard to find online